# Unaccepting an answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I had accepted an answer which preceded another answer by about 1/2 hour. At the time, the answer I accepted seemed quite acceptable.

Subsequently reviewing both answers weeks later, I can appreciate the second answer much more.

I was surprised to see I could actually unaccept an answer yet weeks later, yet even so, I am reluctant to do so for a variety of ethical considerations.

Do I have any alternatives other than offering a bounty or sending a comment?

Thanks

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8787/how-ethical-is-accepting-an-answer-and-then-accepting-another-one-later-for-the

Comment: What are your "variety of ethical considerations"?  I don't really see any ethical issue here.  If you are concerned about offending the first answerer, you could leave them a comment praising their answer but explaining why you accepted the other one.